# Obter cotações de moedas a partir de data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e gostaria de saber se há algum meio de obter cotações de moeda a partir de uma data X (não necessáriamente será o dia atual) via consumo de WebService.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do voto de fechar.

Comment: Acredito que seja pq não foi especificado da onde vem essas cotações, se é de um banco de dados próprio, arquivo de texto, web service etc.

Comment: @rray Entendi. Editei informando que é via WebService.

Comment: Não sei os outros mas eu votei para fechar porque você não mostrou o que fez, não deu detalhes do que precisa, onde está seu erro, não deixou claro do que precisa, enfim, nem sabemos que tipo de resposta será satisfatória. Mas se for só uma lista de *links* onde pode pegar isto, também é ampla segundo a definição deste motivo de fechamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Por Webservice

[Conheço o CurrencyConvertor do webservicex.net](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx). Basta importar a referência Web.

## Por REST API

[Há o OpenExchangeRates](https://openexchangerates.org/documentation).

Comment: Se der para trazer informação desses links para aqui seria excelente. Essa API parece interessante, acho que seria bom para outros ter informação em português aqui.

Comment: @Sergio O primeiro não tem muito segredo. O Visual Studio faz tudo sozinho pra importar. Do segundo é uma documentação grande.